# passing list argument to be iterated on -int not iterable

Tags: python, list, int, iterable

I have a python function that needs to write an arbirary number of bytes to a bus:

```
def Writebytes(self,values):
    for byte in values:
        self.writebyte(byte)
```

The idea is you pass it a list of bytes and it writes them all out to the bus, e.g.

```
data=[0x10,0x33,0x14]
object.Writebytes(data)
```

i'd like to support a single byte write without the [ ] so that you can enter:

```
data=0x00
object.Writebytes(data)
```

the aim to be to ease usage. However you cannot iterate over the int that is passed to Writebytes. Is there a simple way to coerce the input to always be a list? (preferably in the function definition..)

All this iterables stuff is new to me in my first week of Python (which has gone quite well actually, to python's credit). I'm using Python3 mostly on an RPi btw..

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a `try except` statement

```
def Writebytes(self,values):
    try:
        for byte in values:
            self.writebyte(byte)
    except TypeError:
        self.writebyte(values)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this seems like a neat way around it. I can see that it is robust as you mentioned. Thanks for the great advice- reallty appreciated.